# How to get an AVG of date time field which is converted in specific format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have a table where start and end date is available which are in `datetime` format.

I have two requirements.

- Get the difference in `hh:mm:ss` format.
- Get the AVG of that time.

I am able to achieve first requirement but not sure how to get AVG after that. Do I need to cast on the statement where I am getting `hh:mm:ss`?

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @StartDate2 DATETIME, @EndDate2 DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = '2018-07-17 10:56:06.003';
SET @EndDate = '2018-07-17 10:57:15.967';
SET @StartDate2 = '2018-06-06 15:57:47.823';
SET @EndDate2 = '2018-06-06 16:01:28.707';

SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate,
       @EndDate AS EndDate,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEDIFF(s, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 3600)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEDIFF(s, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 3600 / 60)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (DATEDIFF(s, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 60)) AS [hh:mm:ss],
      0 as placeholder
UNION
SELECT @StartDate2 AS StartDate2,
       @EndDate2 AS EndDate2,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEDIFF(s, @StartDate2, @EndDate2) / 3600)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEDIFF(s, @StartDate2, @EndDate2) % 3600 / 60)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (DATEDIFF(s, @StartDate2, @EndDate2) % 60)) AS [hh:mm:ss],
      0 as placeholder;
```

**Result:**

```
StartDate               EndDate                 hh:mm:ss          placeholder
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------- -----------
2018-06-06 15:57:47.823 2018-06-06 16:01:28.707 0:3:41            0
2018-07-17 10:56:06.003 2018-07-17 10:57:15.967 0:1:9             0
```

Here, my expected result in `placeholder` would be average of 3:41 and 1:9.

Comment: With your actual SQL, are you doing this in-line in a SQL query, or in a multi-line SP?

Comment: @Zack in-line query.